# There doesn't seem to be any way to automatically make 'Left' and 'Right' vertex groups. Does anyone have any tips or work arounds for this?

Tags: python, vertex-groups, mirror-modifier

I'm modelling a human body using python code in blender. The way I'm doing it right now, I start with half a cube that has a mirror modifier on it and work from there. I'm adding vertex groups for body parts like the chest or the shoulders. For body parts that come in pairs, like the shoulders, I would want to make two separate vertex groups, one for the left shoulder and one for the right. Is there any way to quickly do this besides just creating them and assigning them after I apply the mirror modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the vertex groups follow a proper [naming convention](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html#data) and exist, the weights can be automatically mirrored by the mirror modifier.

[image: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html#data]

Comment: OOOOHHHH! Thanks a ton, this is exactly correct.